# Dual spaces and weak solutions.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have two questions:

(1) $H^{-1}$ space is defined as the dual space of $H_{0}^{1}$, so is the dual space of $H^{1}$ also $H^{-1}$? Or is it correct to act an $T\in H^{-1}$ on a function $u\in H^{1}$?

(2) For the Poisson problem $-\Delta u=f$ with boundary condition $u=g$ for proper conditions on the data and domain. If there exists $w\in H^{1}$ with $w=g$ on the boundary s.t. it holds for all $v\in H_{0}^{1}$ that $\int \nabla w \nabla v=\int fv$, then what can we say about this $w$? Can we get that $w$ is the weak solution of the Poisson problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. $H^1_0$ is contained in $H^1$ and has the same norm, so $H^{-1}$ must be contained in the dual of $H^1$. It turns out that it is a proper subset of the actual dual of $H^1$.
2. Sure, this is usually the definition of the weak solution (though we have to interpret "$w=g$ on the boundary" using the trace operator). In particular you are correct to consider only $v \in H^1_0$ rather than $v \in H^1$. I find this easier to understand in the context of the corresponding variational problem: you should be able to add a variation $v$ to a solution candidate $u$ and get another solution candidate. For Dirichlet conditions this means the variations must vanish on the boundary. Then playing with it a bit you find that variations in the variational context are the same as test functions in the distributional context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please give a little more explicite information of the dual space of $H^{1}$? For the second, does that necessary condition imply the existence? And can we use $w$ itself as a test function to show the boundedness of certain norms?

Comment: @ShijieDong Through Riesz, each bounded linear functional on $H^1$ is given by the $H^1$ inner product of a fixed element of $H^1$ with its argument. I don't understand your other questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. In Evans' PDE book, he transferred the inhomogeneous boundary condition to the homogeneous one, then the test function space and the trial space are the same. So we can use the weak solution as a test function, and then everything works out. But in the above, the situation is quite different. I wonder how the procedure will be.